# Connecting Android Studio to Internet using Tor

Tags: android-studio, tor

I have Tor Connected to the Internet and I want to use it for connecting Android Studio:
[image]

And I have changed proxy settings in Android Studio:

[image]

But Android Studio always asks me for Proxy Authentication, and I couldn't connect Android Studio to the Internet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use tor as username and password